# Is there a way to save data as a csv file within plumber codes?

Tags: r, plumber

I am new to using the plumber package and RESTful API. When I am working on the local machine, it is possible to add a line within the @get function to write to data files within the folder. I can't seem to get the same thing to work when I host it on the virtual machine. What might be the problem?

I used write.table() below, which worked fine when its on my local machine. i.e. I am able to append data to "data.csv" accordingly.  Is it not possible in the case of a running the script on the virtual machine?

```
#* @get /predict_petal_length
get_predict_length <- function(petal_width){
# convert the input to a number
petal_width <- as.numeric(petal_width)
# create the prediction data frame
input_data <- data.frame(Petal.Width=as.numeric(petal_width))
write.table(input_data,"data.csv",append = TRUE,col.names = FALSE)
# create the prediction
predict(model,input_data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not have write permission to the folder your are trying to write to? What is your virtual machine configuration?

Try using full path, use a path you are sure the R process can write to on the virtual machine.

instead of "data.csv", "/tmp/plumber/data.csv" or something like that

Comment: i am working through this using Docker. So i think that might be the problem. It seems that writing files files within Docker is close to impossible. Anyway, I found this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host If there is a solution, I will be happy to try. Thanks.

Comment: Since its in Docker, the solution is to mount a volume. there is an example here https://www.cascadia-analytics.com/2018/07/23/docker-r-p3.html